# Using the normalization condition and what makes a wave function of a particle qualify that can move along the entire real axis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, normalization

Which one of the following functions, and why, qualifies to be a wave function of a particle that can move along the entire real axis.

$$
\begin{align}
(a)\,\,&\Psi(x)=A~e^{-x^2} \\
(b)\,\,&\Psi(x)=A~e^{-x} \\
(c)\,\,&\Psi(x)=A\tan x \\
(d)\,\,&\Psi(x)=A\frac{\sin x}{x} \\
(e)\,\,&\Psi(x)=A~e^{-|x|} \\
\end{align}
$$

I know what the normalization condition is. I also know the answers for this problem is A and E but, I'm not exactly sure how to plug these into the normalization condition and solving for it.

Comment: But the question asks WHY they are "good" wavefunctions. That is all you need to answer to

Comment: well wouldn't working out the normalization say why it qualifies?

Comment: You don't need to solve integrals. It only suffices to show they are convergent.

Comment: Okay. I think I understand that.

Comment: could you show me how you do it for part A)?

Comment: I don't like what I am getting out of it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example **type** questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/75633) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/75633). You might want to consider posting in [some other Physics website](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/391/75633), such as the [PhysicsForums](https://www.physicsforums.com/forums/homework-and-coursework-questions.152/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Expanding on the comment above, you need to show that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \Psi^2 (x) ~ dx <\infty $. To check this, eliminate the wavefunctions which "blow up" or are simply not defined at the origin $x=0$. This eliminates c) and d). b) is eliminated because for $x<0$ the exponential is increasing indefinitely as x decreases. You are left with a) and e). You have that e) is continuous everywhere and decays exponentially to $\pm\infty$, so the integral exists as a number. 
For a), this is a typical gaussian. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function